# CSI-2 MIPI Interface

Tags: embedded, android-camera, embedded-linux, bsp

In my project, we have used ov5640 camera module which will transfer the captured data in serial to Toshiba bridge. Toshiba bridge will send the received data in parallel to the processor.

When I was working on parallel camera, it is registered as VIN device so, when we run GStreamer application, the camera starts capturing data.

But the serial camera is not registered as VIN device then how to start camera to capture the image?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me, when you say serial you mean USB? You can use V4L2 to capture video stream from USB device.

Comment: You probably need a driver to create the device.

Comment: @PierreOlivier driver as I see is in vanilla (I don't give a sh*t of Android) _drivers/media/i2c/ov5640.c_.